# iPhone 8: WiFi only connects to certain domains, resetting network settings did nothing

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, domain

My WiFi is working perfectly fine throughout the house (no other device is having issues) and for some reason my phone just stopped connecting in certain apps and sites. For example it will connect to Instagram but will refuse to connect to Spotify.

I can connect to any domain on cellular still. Resetting network settings did nothing, I tried twice, I tried hard resetting and whatever else I could think of and nothing else was doing it. I tried connecting to the multiple different networks in my house. I’m not sure what else to do on my end or if I will have to contact Apple, or if the phones adapter just suddenly stopped working?

Comment: Try cycling WiFi on and off.  I have an iPad and iPhone that does the same thing and that fixes it. I've narrowed it down to an issue with iOS and what  I believe to be its DNS caching.

Comment: If resetting your router fixed the problem, then post is as an answer and mark it as such.  Don't leave an edit in the question as it can't be marked as solved.  Remember, we're not Reddit.